# How to fix React Warning

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I get this warning in my browser

> Warning: validateDOMNesting(...):  cannot appear as a descendant of
>   .
>       in a (at App.js:79)
>       in a (created by LinkAnchor)
>       in LinkAnchor (created by Context.Consumer)
>       in Link (at App.js:79)
>       in nav (at App.js:77)
>       in header (at App.js:70)
>       in div (at App.js:68)
>       in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
>       in BrowserRouter (at App.js:67)
>       in App (created by ConnectFunction)
>       in ConnectFunction (at src/index.js:23)
>       in Provider (at src/index.js:22)

from below code

```
 <Link to={'/addRobo'} className="nav-link"><a className="f6 f5-l link bg-animate black-80 hover-bg-light-green dib pa3 ph4-l" href="1">Add Robot</a></Link>
```

Also this code

```
import React, {
    Component
} from 'react';
import {
    Link,
    Route,
    Switch
} from 'react-router-dom';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router
} from 'react-router-dom';
import {
    connect
} from 'react-redux';
import {
    setSearchField,
    requestRobots
} from '../actions';
import CardList from '../components/CardList';
import SearchBox from '../components/SearchBox';
import Scroll from '../components/Scroll';
import ErrorBoundry from '../components/ErrorBoundry';
import AddRobot from '../components/AddRobot';
import UppdateRobot from '../components/UpdateRobot';
import DeleteRobot from '../components/DeleteRobot';
import './App.css';

// parameter state comes from index.js provider store state(rootReducers)
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        searchField: state.searchRobots.searchField,
        robots: state.manage_data.robots,
        isPending: state.manage_data.isPending
    }
}

// dispatch the DOM changes to call an action. note mapStateToProps returns object, mapDispatchToProps returns function
// the function returns an object then uses connect to change the data from redecers.
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        onSearchChange: (event) => dispatch(setSearchField(event.target.value)),
        onRequestRobots: () => dispatch(requestRobots()),
    }
}

class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.props.userinfo);
        this.props.onRequestRobots();
    }

    render() {
            const {
                robots,
                searchField,
                onSearchChange,
                isPending
            } = this.props;
            const stylecur = {
                fill: 'currentcolor'
            };
            const filteredRobots = robots.filter(robot => {
                return robot.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase());
            })
            const routes = [{
                    id: 1,
                    path: '/addRobo',
                    component: AddRobot
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    path: '/updateRobo',
                    component: UppdateRobot
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    path: '/searchRobo',
                    component: SearchBox
                },
                {
                    id: 4,
                    path: '/delRobo',
                    component: DeleteRobot
                }
            ];
            return ( <
                Router >
                <
                div className = 'tc' >

                <
                header className = "bg-white black-80 tc pv4 avenir" >
                <
                a href = ""
                className = "bg-black-80 ba b--black dib pa3 w2 h2 br-100" >
                <
                svg className = "white"
                data - icon = "skull"
                viewBox = "0 0 32 32"
                style = {
                    stylecur
                } >
                <
                title > skull icon < /title><path d="M16 0 C6 0 2 4 2 14 L2 22 L6 24 L6 30 L26 30 L26 24 L30 22 L30 14 C30 4 26 0 16 0 M9 12 A4.5 4.5 0 0 1 9 21 A4.5 4.5 0 0 1 9 12 M23 12 A4.5 4.5 0 0 1 23 21 A4.5 4.5 0 0 1 23 12"></path > < /svg> <
                /a> <
                h1 className = "mt2 mb0 baskerville i fw1 f1" > RoboFriends < /h1> <
                h2 className = "mt2 mb0 f6 fw4 ttu tracked" > Create an ensembe of Robot with your friends! < /h2> <
                nav className = "bt bb tc mw7 center mt4" >
                <
                a className = "f6 f5-l link bg-animate black-80 hover-bg-lightest-blue dib pa3 ph4-l"
                href = "/" > Home < /a> <
                Link to = {
                    '/addRobo'
                }
                className = "nav-link" > < a className = "f6 f5-l link bg-animate black-80 hover-bg-light-green dib pa3 ph4-l"
                href = "1" > Add Robot < /a></Link >
                <
                Link to = {
                    '/updateRobo'
                }
                className = "nav-link" > < a className = "f6 f5-l link bg-animate black-80 hover-bg-light-blue dib pa3 ph4-l" > Update Robot < /a></Link >
                <
                Link to = {
                    '/searchRobo'
                }
                className = "nav-link" > < a className = "f6 f5-l link bg-animate black-80 hover-bg-light-pink dib pa3 ph4-l" > Search Robot < /a></Link >
                <
                a className = "f6 f5-l link bg-animate black-80 hover-bg-light-yellow dib pa3 ph4-l" > < Link to = {
                    '/delRobo'
                }
                className = "nav-link" > Delete Robot < /Link></a >
                <
                /nav> <
                /header> <
                Switch > {
                    routes.map(({
                            id,
                            path,
                            component: Component
                        }) => ( <
                            Route key = {
                                id
                            }
                            path = {
                                path
                            }
                            component = {
                                Component
                            } // sans the angle brackets </>
                            />))
                        } <
                        /Switch>   <
                        Scroll > {
                            isPending ? < h1 > Loading < /h1> : <
                            ErrorBoundry >
                            <
                            CardList robots = {
                                filteredRobots
                            }
                            /> <
                            /ErrorBoundry>
                        } <
                        /Scroll> <
                        /div> <
                        /Router>
                    );
                }
            }

            // action done from mapDispatchToProps will channge state from mapStateToProps
            export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

Comment: Link already consists of anchor tag i.e <a></a> and you are using it inside Link that's why facing issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `<Link>` component already renders an `<a>` tag and you're using `<a>` inside a `<Link>` so it ends up being `<a><a></a></a>` which is why you're getting the warning

Answer (score 0):

React Link tag already implemented a(anchor) tag inside so you don't need to use anchor tag while developing react application

There are two way you can define anchor tag in `react-router-dom`

1- using **Link**

2- using **NavLink**

```
<Link to="/">Home</Link>
 or 
<NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink>
```

> Don't define href in react-routing, in `react-router-dom` href==**to**